# What is the best way to cache data on reactjs

Tags: reactjs, caching

I have created a website that uses a large amount of data from the server, it slows down the display of data, I want to know what is the best way to save the data in the cache for reactjs  and update it only if there is a change in data base  thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lot of strategies that you can use to cache data:

- Use a library like React Query or Relay that automatically caches data
- Use a library like redux-persist along with redux to cache data.

Alternatively, if performance is impacted because you are showing a big list of data, you should use some virtualisation on the client like react-virtualised.

Comment: our problem is that we use the state management of redux and we need chaching, does redux persist allow this ?

Comment: Yes, redux persist will cache data in local storage.

Comment: how to notify my my  users reducer for exemple that an other user was added to the  db so it can update the cache ?

Comment: you have to update the state like you normally do with actions.

Comment: how to update the cached data only if it change on the db , like how do i fetch the cached data , and in the same time hydrate the data if needed ?